# Going from MySQL to SQLite

Tags: python

I'm a PHP developer and have been using MySQL with PHPmyadmin or HeidiSQL for database management.  I get connection details(ip address,database name,user,password) then i can access the database remotely.

I'm now learning Python and Flask and this uses SQLite.  Is there a database management software so i can view the database created and navigate tables?

If not what do i use to navigate the database?

For example i have created the table `Entry`

```
class Entry(flask_db.Model):
    title = CharField()
    slug = CharField(unique=True)
    content = TextField()
    published = BooleanField(index=True)
    timestamp = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, index=True)


def main():
    database.create_tables([Entry], safe=True)
```

In PHPmyadmin there is a GUI to navigate database..  What do i do for SQLite?

Comment: Try DBeaver, it has great features and it's free. You should be able to connect to your databases with the host info regardless of the db management software.

Comment: What's the problem to keep using MySQL with Flask? Or other db you like... Otherwise there are ton of SQLite tools

Comment: Tutorials for Flask/DJango etc tend to use sqlite because it's bundled with Python.  But there's no problems using MySQL or Postgres, especially if there's an ORM between the webapp and the db (Flask apps tend to use SQLAlchemy, Django has its own ORM)